# Drag down formula

Tags: vba, excel

I have to apply a formula in column S (=concatenate(p1,q2,r3). This formula has to copy down until column end.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-3],RC[-2],RC[-1])"

Range("S1").Select

Selection.copy

Range("S:S").Select

ActiveSheet.Paste

Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: I am curios as to why this question was down voted. I assume the answer is that the code is wrong. but isn't it the whole point of SO? to correct mistakes in coding, among other goals? And come to think of it, most questions with code in them have one or more code mistakes in them, right? so why aren't those questions necessarily down voted? (to clarify, I have no relation to the OP, simply trying to make sense of it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not want the formula all the way to the bottom of column S; you only need it to the last used cell in columns P, Q and R.

```
dim lr as long

with worksheets("sheet1")
    lr = application.max(.cells(.rows.count, "P").end(xlup).row, _
                         .cells(.rows.count, "Q").end(xlup).row, _
                         .cells(.rows.count, "R").end(xlup).row)
    .range(.cells(1, "S"), .cells(lr, "S")).FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-3], RC[-2], RC[-1])"
end with
```

Comment: i need to copy and special paste

Comment: Unless this is a homework question, then **no** you do **not** have to copy & paste. You can write a formula into all of the cells at once.

Comment: i understand..but once formula is applied then i need to delete p,q, & r column so that i need to copy S column and special paste it